# Simulating a loading spinner before debounce

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, lodash, es6-promise, debouncing

does anyone know how can I execute the this.isLoading = true before the debounce in this method?

It was supposed to be a loading spinner that will be animated when making async call via axios.

```
    methods: {
        searchAdminUsers: _.debounce(function(query) {
            this.isLoading = true       
            axios.get('api/searchEmployees?format=json', { params: { q:query } })
            .then(response => {
                let data = response.data.map(item => (
                    { text: `${item.FIRSTNAME} ${item.LASTNAME} - ${item.POSITION}`, id: item.ID }
                ))
                this.options = data
                this.isLoading = false
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
          })
        }, 250)
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create another method that changes `this.isLoading`, and invokes the debounces method.

```
methods: {
    wrapSearchAdminUsers(query) {
      this.isLoading = true

      this.searchAdminUsers(query)
    }

    searchAdminUsers: _.debounce(function(query) {
        axios.get('api/searchEmployees?format=json', { params: { q:query } })
        .then(response => {
            let data = response.data.map(item => (
                { text: `${item.FIRSTNAME} ${item.LASTNAME} - ${item.POSITION}`, id: item.ID }
            ))
            this.options = data
            this.isLoading = false
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    }, 250)
}
```

Comment: Appreciated Ori